# Can and Should I cache symfony2 getUser()

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle

I am using Symfony ( current version 2.6.4 ) whenever I want to check if a user is loggedin ( I am also using FOSUserBundle ) I use `$user = $this->getUser();` in my controller which works out just fine but if I open 10 links in 1 second this query is repeated for all 10 pages in that second, not so ideal in my option. So my question is, is there a way to cache this query for say 60 seconds and is it even advisable, will it affect new registrations or something. I am using APC as my doctrine cache but if someone knows the answer please also tell us how to use other ways incase other people also wonder how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: check the symfony2 profiler db-query i guess the query takes about  5-10ms

Comment: @johnSmith I know it doesn't take too long, although when you integrate it with HWIOauth Bundle it takes longer because you are adding more columns, so if I add a login with Google, Facebook, Twitter and 10-15 others it takes much longer and it is queried on every page, every time for every logged in user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with, sql databases do a good job of automatically caching queries.  So while there is some overhead in composing and sending the query to the server, the server itself will respond very quickly.  You won't save much be adding another cache.

Should you still try and optimize?  In your example of 10 requests per second one assumes that the requests are actually doing something besides getting the user.  It's up to you to decide if caching the query will actually speed things up.  In most cases the answer will be no.  Trying to save every possible microsecond is called premature optimization and is something to avoid.

Having said that, it's worthwhile to look at what the security system is doing. Selected user information is stored in the session.  You can use the debug profile bar to look at it.  For each request, the security system pulls the user out of the session and then calls $user = $userProvider->refreshUser($user);  By default, refreshUser is what causes the database to be queried.

You can easily plug in your own user provider (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html) which just returns $user.  No database interaction at all.  Of course if the user's database information does change then they will need to log out and then log back in to see the changes.  Or do something else to trigger a real refresh.  But for many apps, not refreshing at all will work just fine.

It would also be easy enough to put a time stamp into the session.  Your refreshUser method could then use the time stamp to decide if a refresh was actually needed.

So it's easy enough to eliminate the query and actually worthwhile just as a learning experience.  Security is one of the more complicated components.  The more you understand it the better off you will be.  Customizing a user provider is one of the easier things to do.

I just saw your comment about the OAuthBundle.  I have not used the bundle in awhile.  Implemented my own but I'm surprised that it's hitting the oauth server on each request.  If it is then this would in fact be a good use case for overriding the user provider.  But I'd be surprised if it was really doing that just for user information.

Comment: This is indeed a very good answer and should point me right direction. There are a few things I would like to point out, I think you have the wrong definition of "premature optimization". I believe it to be when people try to optimize an app before finishing coding it. I believe there are many top notch developers at top sites whose living is entirely dependent on "Trying to save every possible microsecond". Lastly, on the HWIOauth Bundle, it doesn't hit the server but rather when integrated with FOSUserBundle it adds 2 columns per Oauth Client in the table that getUser() queries each time.